# tsql to return the datafile for an index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 3 data files for the Primary filegroup of a database in SQL Server 2005.  Is it possible to determine which data file a particular index resides on, or do they live in more than one datafile within the filegroup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects such as tabkes and indexes are built on a filegroup, not a file. The index wiLl most likely reside in all fiLes within the file group. There are a few outlying cases where this is not true, such as if more files have been added, causing a file allocation hotspot, etc, but SQL Server uses a proportional fill algorithm for the files, and fills them evenly.

You can see for sure by running

```
DBCC IND('myDatabase','myTable',2)
```

Where 2 is the indexID of the index you are interested in.

This will show you the fileID of each page

Answer (score 2):

```
select  object_name(i.id) as TableName
,       i.name as IndexName
,       fg.name as FilegroupName
,       df.name as FileName
,       df.physical_name as FilePhysicalName
from    sys.sysindexes i
join    sys.filegroups fg
on      fg.data_space_id = i.groupid
join    sys.database_files df
on      df.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id
join    sys.data_spaces ds
on      ds.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id
where   objectproperty(i.id,'IsUserTable') = 1
```